# Not getting the correct current time in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, datetime

I tried to obtain the current date and time using

```
$date = new Zend_Date();
echo $date;
```

this gives me the correct date, but the time is incorrect.
It should be **Jul 13, 2012 3:14:42 PM**, but it displays **Jul 13, 2012 9:32:42 AM**.

Why is this?

Comment: You may need to set a specific zone.

Comment: yes, I'm testing on localhost.. 
in my `php.ini`, I set the `date.timezone` to `ASIA` but still it's not working.

Comment: The time depends on the timezone of the locale. Just be explicit in your calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your comment implies that you set timezone to `ASIA`. From the date/time you posted in your question, I guess you need to set it to.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
```

Give it a try or set it directly in your php.ini.

Answer (score 1):

set your timezone as default timezone.

// eg: timezone for a German in Germany

`date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');`